# name error while trying selenium to open google

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

im trying the selenium webdriver to open google via chrome but im getting an error

```
 from selenium import webdriver

driver = web.driver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\sahay\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

this is the error which im getting:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sahay/Desktop/python/save/open_google.py", line 3, in 
    driver = web.driver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\sahay\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
NameError: name 'web' is not defined

thanks for helping a fellow noob out!

Comment: It should be `webdriver`, not `web.driver`.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 mistakes, please correct it as below and you'll be good to go.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
driver.get('http://www.google.com/');
```

Comment: It should be `from selenium import webdriver` and `webdriver.Chrome()`, and Python doesn't have `new`.

Comment: im getting an invalid syntax highlighted at d(WebDriver driver)

Comment: @AaryanshSahay Becauses it is invalid. You just need to remove the `.` from `web.driver`

Comment: The OP has a syntax problem, so your solution is to give him other language syntax?

Comment: I just modified my answer with python.!

Answer (score 0):

show this alternative way: Python webbrowser.open() to open Chrome browser

I use it for windows, if you have another system, comment the windows link line and active the line of your system

```
import webbrowser

url = 'http://docs.python.org/'

# MacOS
#chrome_path = 'open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app %s'

# Windows
chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'

# Linux
# chrome_path = '/usr/bin/google-chrome %s'

webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
```